Call to undefined function Magento\Framework\System\ftp_connect()
Since I updated my PHP 8.1 to 8.2 using Adobe Commerce 2.4.7, I started to have exception issues when using FTP OOTB features.
I want to detect the reason and fix it. How could I do it?

Since PHP 8.2.15 removed the FTP extension, you must install it on your server and specify its dependencies on Composer.
How to fix it using Docker
How to add FTP extension dependency on Composer file
How to add FTP extension on your Dockerfile
How to install it on Ubuntu
If you use PHP 8.3, update the commands below before running it.
sudo apt update
sudo apt install php8.2-ftp
sudo apt install php-ftp

Then, restart your web server.
sudo systemctl restart apache2 # For Apache
sudo systemctl restart php8.2-fpm # For NGINX

